# Django packaging project with multiple apps

Tags: django, packaging

I'm trying to package my Django project without success. My project looks like this:

```
dsbg/
  manage.py

  dsbg/
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py

  app1/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py

  app2/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py

  settings/
    base.py
    local.py
    prod.py

  static/
        app1/
            images/
                background.gif
            style.css

  templates/
        home.html
        app1/
            detail.html
            index.html
        app2/
            detail.html
            index.html
```

I followed the procedure [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app) but I'm not sure I'm doing the right things (their example has only one app: polls). I did the following:

- move apps + static + templates directories in new directory django-dsbg (keeping dsbg and settings in root)
- in django-dsbg, create setup.py file, specifying packages files (app1 and app2) and create MANIFEST.in to include static and templates directories.
- in django-dsbg, run:

  ```
   python setup.py sdist
  ```
- in the parent directory of django-dsbg, run:

  ```
   pip install --user django-dsbg/dist/django-dsbg-0.1.tar.gz
  ```

After that, the project looks like this:

```
dsbg/
  manage.py

  settings/
    base.py
    local.py
    prod.py

  dsbg/
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py

  django-dsbg/
    LICENSE
    MANIFEST.in
    README.rst
    app1/
       models.py
       views.py
       urls.py
    app2/
       models.py
       views.py
       urls.py
    templates/
       home.html
       app1/
         ...
       app2/
         ...
    static/
       ...
```

Now at the root directory (the top dsbg), I try to start the server:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.local
```

The server is starting well but when pointing at localhost, the browser says:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at / home.html. 
...
Python Path: ['/home/patrick/django/dsbg/dsbg',
              ...
              '/home/patrick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

This home.html file is located in django-dsbg/templates. Neither dsbg/dsbg nor .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages directories contain home.html. The latter contains all my apps but not the static or the templates directory.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Patrick

Comment: Did you ever figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need the absolute path to templates, doesn't matter where the apps are located, you could always just

```
TEMPLATES_DIRS = ('/home/user/dsbg/django-dsbg/templates', )
```

or

```
# Django 1.8 +
Dirs = ['templates']
```

Comment: I tried it, same result. I suspect that there is maybe something wrong with my new project structure. Is it ok in your opinion (settings, dsbg and django-dsbg at the same level)? Note: it worked with the original structure, before I tried to package my project; I mean there was no problem finding templates.